# Migrations from database

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have created the schema through MySQL Workbench and synchronized it with the database.

All the tables are there in database. Now when I use the

```
php artisan migrate
```

command, is there an option to take the fields director from the database instead of specifying the fields name.

Also could you please suggest any other tools on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Laravel Migrations Generator](https://github.com/xethron/migrations-generator) will help us generate migration source code from existed database in Laravel 4.

Answer (score 0):

so if you already have your sql schema, created in mysql workbench, then you'd need to put that schema into laravel migrations using the [schema builder](http://laravel.com/docs/schema).

there are tools that make this part easier:

- http://www.laravelsd.com/ - kinda like mysql workbench, with an export possibility to laravel migration code
- https://github.com/XCMer/larry-four-generator writes existing databases to laravel migration code

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use our tool Skipper (https://www.skipper18.com) We introduced Laravel support a month ago and now, in a beta phase, it is free for Laraver users.

Skipper allows you to import your MySQL Workbench project directly (or it is possible to import existing database too) and then export migrations and object files from Skipper to your Laravel project.

The benefit of this solution is that you can maintain your ORM schema directly in Skipper and continuously update model object files and create new migrations automatically from the application without the necessity to write any code manually.

If you want to try it, you can download it here https://www.skipper18.com/en/download, and in the initial application license screen select "Laravel Beta license".